# How to Incorporate a memory allocator in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am working on a lock free data structure, and I have been examining the code at [libcds](http://libcds.sourceforge.net/), but I can not seem to figure out how to incorporate there memory allocator into my class file.

```
template<class KEY, class VALUE>
class DataStruc{
public:
```

I have never used custom memory allocators before, and I am having trouble figuring out how to approach incorporating it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to implement operator new() for your class. Your implementation should get memory from an instance of the allocator.

In the header file for your class, you'll need to declare the allocation/deallocation operators:

```
public:
    void * operator new(size_t size);
    void * operator delete(void * obj, size_t size);
    void * operator new[](size_t size);
    void * operator delete[](void * obj, size_t size);
```

Then you need to implement them. Somewhere you need to instantiate an allocator; maybe just make it a static in the file where you implement these operators. Then, just looking at the API docs on that web site, you'd do something like the below. I put in the asserts because I can't see how to pass the object size to that allocator; that effectively means that YourClass better not serve as a parent to other classes.

```
static cds::details::Allocator<YourClass> allocator;

void * YourClass::operator new(size_t size) { 
    assert size == sizeof(YourClass);
    return allocator.New();
}

void * YourClass::operator new[](size_t size) { 
    return allocator.NewArray(size/sizeof(YourClass));
}

void YourClass::operator delete(void * object, size_t size) { 
    return allocator.Delete(object);
}

void YourClass::operator delete[](void * object, size_t size) { 
    return allocator.DeleteArray(object, size/sizeof(YourClass));
}
```

I'm not too happy with the asserts and divisions, but it's late and I'm tired. Maybe somebody else knows a more elegant way to make these APIs match up a bit better. But this'd work.

Comment: in regard to the library i mentioned, could you give me a code example?
My code has to allocate a struct Book, and an array of pointers to book.

Thanks so much

Comment: Disclaimer: I know nothing about that library other than what I learned from a 30-second browse of the web site. But I will edit my answer to add some code, assuming the claims on that site are valid and correct.

Comment: This is what I needed, I really had no idea where to start, thanks a bunch, I will let u know how integration goes!

Answer (score 0):

Read this post on some insight how to implement a custom memory allocation system:
http://www.stevestreeting.com/2008/06/28/memory-man/

His post is in reference to the custom memory allocation system implemented in the open source Ogre3D graphics library. You can download its source code and see how it is done there at http://www.ogre3d.org/download/source